# Why Iterator<Entry<Integer, Double> cannot be converted to Iterator<Entry<? extends Integer, ? extends Double>>

Tags: java, guava

I have the sample code below attempting to construct an immutable map out of an iterable:

```
ImmutableList<Entry<Integer, Double>> list = ImmutableList.of(
    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Double>(4, 2d),
    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Double>(16, 4d));
ImmutableMap.<Integer, Double>builder().putAll(list); // No error
ImmutableMap.<Integer, Double>builder().putAll(() -> list.stream().iterator()); // Error - cannot convert type...
```

I am getting the error `Bad return type in lambda expression: Iterator<Entry<Integer, Double>> cannot be converted to Iterator<Entry<? extends Integer, ? extends Double>>`. From my understanding this should be valid because Integer is a valid upper bound of Integer, and Double is a valid upper bound of Double. What is the problem here and how can I fix specifically the iterator code?

I need to fix the iterator code in particular since I am trying to transform another collection into a map like below. I am using guava on android so do not have access to the default guava collect() methods (though I think I can implement them manually if there is really no other way to do this).

```
ImmutableList<Integer> numberList = ImmutableList.of(2,4,8,12,16,24,32);
ImmutableMap.<Integer, Double>builder().putAll(() -> 
   numberList.stream().map(num -> 
       (Entry<Integer, Double>) new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Double>(num, Math.sqrt(num))).iterator());
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh boy, this one is ugly.

You're right that `Entry<? extends Integer, ? extends Double>` is a "subtype" of `Entry<Integer, Double>` (I think it's not technically called a subtype, but is effectively one). But, as you may know, `Iterator<Subtype>` is *not* a subtype of `Iterator<Supertype>`. Instead you have to do `Iterator<? extends Subtype>`.

So you'd need to add just one more `? extends` in there:

```
Iterator<? extends Entry<? extends Integer, ? extends Double>>
         ^^^^^^^^^
```

I'm not sure offhand what the best way to do that is, though.

Answer (score -1):

Integer is not a valid upper bound of Integer, you can't extend class A from class A. For example you can't write this:
Public class Actor extends Actor{
}
So to solve your problem make Number instead Integer like this Iterator<Entry<? extends Number, ?extends Number>>

Comment: [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) indicate that a upper bound matches the type and any subtype:

"The upper bounded wildcard, <? extends Foo>, where Foo is any type, matches Foo and any subtype of Foo."